# Multiple conditions in "if else" statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to use multiple conditions in the `if else` statement, I would say: if the scroll-top is greater than 0 and `.skiptranslate` is visible do this ... of course my code does not work ...
Any suggestions?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('.header-main').css({
            "position" : "fixed",
            "top" : "0"
        }); 

    if else ($(window).scrollTop() > 0 && $('.skiptranslate').is(':visible')) {
        $('.header-main').css({
            "position" : "fixed",
            "top" : "39px"
        }); 

    } else {
        $('.header-main').css({
            "position" : "absolute",
            "top" : "0"
        });         
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your if-else statement is wrong, try the below code in your project and if it works, drink a coffee before the start again.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){        
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0 && $('.skiptranslate').is(':visible')) {
        $('.header-main').css({
            "position" : "fixed",
            "top" : "39px"
        }); 

    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('.header-main').css({
            "position" : "fixed",
            "top" : "0"
        }); 
    } else {
        $('.header-main').css({
            "position" : "absolute",
            "top" : "0"
        });         
    }
});
```

Comment: If the second statement is true, so is the first one so it can never be reached.